# How can i create landscape PDF using android native PdfDocument API?

Tags: android, pdf, mobility

I am using PdfDocument API to write a PDF from View using Android

**Problem**

If am writing PDF of A4 size.
How can i make in landscape mode?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A typical use of the Android PDF APIs looks like this:

```
// create a new document
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

// crate a page description
PageInfo pageInfo = new PageInfo.Builder(300, 300, 1).create();

// start a page
Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

// draw something on the page
View content = getContentView();
content.draw(page.getCanvas());

// finish the page
document.finishPage(page);
. . .
// add more pages
. . .
// write the document content
document.writeTo(getOutputStream());

// close the document
document.close();
```

According to the [developer.android.com reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder.html):

> ```
> public PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder (int pageWidth, int pageHeight, int pageNumber)
> ```
>
> <sub>Added in API level 19</sub>
>
> Creates a new builder with the mandatory page info attributes.
>
> Parameters
>
> `pageWidth`    The page width in PostScript (1/72th of an inch).
>
> `pageHeight`   The page height in PostScript (1/72th of an inch).
>
> `pageNumber`   The page number.

To create a PDF with portrait A4 pages, therefore, you can define the page descriptions like this:

```
PageInfo pageInfo = new PageInfo.Builder(595, 842, 1).create();
```

and for a PDF with landscape A4 pages, you can define them like this:

```
PageInfo pageInfo = new PageInfo.Builder(842, 595, 1).create();
```

Comment: The problem is 595 is not exactly the right number. The result is a width of 209,9 mm instead of 210 mm.

Comment: @Jerry A4 is defined with allowed deviations, and this. 1mm is allowed